# How to install ROOT cern on Ubuntu 15

Tags: root

```
shinee@shinee:~/Downloads/root$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libx11-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libx11-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you add a little more detail to your question please? Let us know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what is your ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

If you encountered the problem with

```
configure: c++11 mode is requested but the current compiler does not support it.
```

while running `./configure linux` on a 64bit ubuntu 15.10, this can be solved by installing/updating your `gcc` and `g++` packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc g++
```

and specifying your architecture in the configure command:

```
./configure linuxx8664gcc
```