# Can I use binaries compiled for Scientific Linux on Ubuntu?

Tags: root, binary

Can I use binaries compiled for Scientific Linux on Ubuntu? I need to use library called ROOT in old version (released in 2010), but can't find binaries for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

No and yes...

No, Scientific Linux is based on Red Hat and they use .rpm-packages; and Ubuntu is based on Debian, so you need .deb-packages.

But you can try to use [alien](https://joeyh.name/code/alien/) to install/convert foreign packages: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto

---

but IMHO compiling it yourself is definitely the better way...!

there were some problems/questions installing [root-system](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=root-system) in the past, so i link them here (maybe they are helpful):
[How do I install root-cern?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39363/how-do-i-install-root-cern)
[Problem trying to install ROOT (by CERN) on 11.04 i386](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192292/problem-trying-to-install-root-by-cern-on-11-04-i386)
[How to install ROOT cern on Ubuntu 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675138/how-to-install-root-cern-on-ubuntu-15)

maybe also the obviously discontinued project *Cern Root debs* is worth a look: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cernrootdebs/

but no matter which method you use for installing (or also compiling)... with a 6 years old package/source on an actual system you might get stuck in a [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

Comment: Yes, I asked this question because I got dependency hell, I can't compile sources by myself. But thanks for your answer. I will probably try different library

Answer (score 1):

SL use RPM and Ubuntu use Dppkg for package management so is unlikely.

Can you compile from source? Do you know the library dependencies?

Comment: No, I can't compile from sources, even if I download all dependencies, **"configure"** is ok, but when try **"make"**, it fails because of compile errors. Strange.

Comment: Have you tried installing the library from the official ubuntu repositories? What is the version of library? Some people maintain old repositories and maybe is at one of them. http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/root-system

Comment: I am getting: "unable to locate package root-system"

Comment: What Ubuntu version your using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS